# Sampling from SDE

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, geometric-brownian, sampling

In the case of the classic Geometric Brownian motion
$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_tdW_t$$
we solve it as 
$$ S_t = S_0  \exp\left[ \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)t + \sigma dW_t\right] $$
and simulate $S_{t_{i+1}} = S(t_i) \exp\left[ \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)(t_{i+1}-t_{i}) + \sigma dW_t\right]$ with $W_t = \sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}Z_{i+1}$.

However, I am working with the slightly different version
$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t^{\beta/2} dW_t$$
When I solve it using the Ito's Lemma, I get
$$S_t = S_0 \exp\left[ \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} S_t^{\beta-2}\right)t + \sigma S^{\beta/2 - 1}_t dW_t\right]$$
and have no idea how to simulate it using normal distribution, since $S_t$ is sitting inside. Is it possible to sample from this process?

Answer (score 2):

No need to use ito's lemma. You can simulate your process directly from the equation:
$$dS_t = \mu S_t dt + \sigma S_t^{\beta/2} dW_t$$
which means that:
$$S_{t_{i+1}}=S_{t_i}+\mu S_{t_i}(t_{i+1}-t_i)+\sigma S_{t_i}^{\beta/2}\sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i}Z_{i}$$
where $Z_i$ is a realization of normal distribution with mean 0 and variance equal to 1.

Comment: How do we know that the joint distribution of the samle is the same as the joint distribution of the stochastic process?